# MS Access Form Text Boxes Freeze

Tags: textbox, ms-access-2016

I have a weird situation with my MS Access 2016 split database.

The back-end is a Azure SQL server DB, the front-end are distributed accde files.

I have a form bound to a linked table with several sub-forms in it.

The form is used to edit single records of the main table.

With some records all works fine ("good") but with some other records ("bad") **the text boxes freeze, not allowing any edits**.

No error messages, they just seem to be locked but the locked property of the text boxes control is set to false. (I've checked this in runtime)

What I've tried so far:

- I can edit all records directly in the linked table
- The properties of the form and controls in both "good" records and
  "bad" records are the same
- I can change the values of check and combo boxes and update the "bad"
  records
- The BIT column has a default value of 0 and nulls are not allowed (no
  NULLS in the table for this field)

I'm running out of ideas. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, so i'll leave the solution in case someone hits the same issue.
I have a subform with a browser control. All i had to do was to add the following line at the end of the main form loading sequence:

```
Me.SF_WEB_BROWSER.SetFocus
```